# SQL column in two possible result sets, use case in WHERE clause to choose one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a situation where I need to create a query where the filters for my query require a result set from 1 of 2 possible places.

I started searching online to see if there was a way to use a `CASE` statement like this:

```
A.Column IN (CASE EXISTS()...THEN (SELECT...)... END)
```

and couldn't find any definitive answers, so I tried making something like this myself but I get the following error and I don't understand why:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

In plain English, what I want my query to do is ONLY filter out parcels where a parcel has a contract contained in a driver table called `Contracts` based on report type. Some reports have many contracts in the driver table and some have none. If a report type does not have contracts in the driver table, use all possible contracts. My constraint is not to use dynamic SQL so this query could be put into a table-valued function

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    IDNum, PName, County, CountyDescription,
    DATENAME(MONTH, ptn) AS ptn_mt_char,
    YEAR(ptn) AS ptn_yr,
    MONTH(ptn) AS ptn_mt,
    ptn
FROM
    (SELECT 
         A.ID AS IDNum, 
         A.PName, A.County, A.CountyDescpription,
         dbo.udf_getPtn(A.ID, 
                        CAST(@ReportType AS VARCHAR), 
                        CAST(@DataDate AS VARCHAR), 
                        CAST(@montha AS VARCHAR), 
                        CAST(@monthb AS VARCHAR), 
                        CAST(@total_fa AS VARCHAR), 
                        CAST(@total_fb AS VARCHAR)) AS ptn
     FROM 
         DB.dbo.PData A
     LEFT JOIN 
         DB.dbo.FData B ON A.ID = B.ID
     WHERE 
         A.Contract IN (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT cnt FROM dbo.Contracts WHERE ReportType = @ReportType AND SubReportType = @SubReportType)
                             THEN (SELECT cnt FROM dbo.Contracts WHERE ReportType = @ReportType AND SubReportType = @SubReportType)
                             ELSE (SELECT DISTINCT ConC FROM DB.dbo.PData)   
                        END)) A 
WHERE 
    ptn IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY 
    ptn, IDNum
```

Comment: You have a couple of major problems with your query already. You are using a scalar function which is a performance timebomb. Secondly you are casting a number of variable to varchar with no length. You need to specify the length or they will default to a single character. Last but not least is you have 5 or 6 queries all jammed into this thing.

Comment: @SeanLange: actually, for `CAST` and `CONVERT`, the default length if no length is specified explicitly is **30 characters**. The **1 char** applies to variable declarations and function/procedure parameters. But I agree - any usage of `VARCHAR` should ***always*** be accompanied by an **explicit length**

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot that in that case it switches to 30. It is one of those times when the length changes. Yet another reason to specify the length because the defaults are not consistent and is easy to forget which is which.

Comment: @SeanLange thank you for the helpful tips. All your points have dramatically helped me to improve the original design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` expression cannot return a multitude of values, thus you cannot use it in conjunction with `IN` the way you think. You could rewrite your `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE (         
       A.Contract IN (SELECT cnt 
                      FROM dbo.Contracts 
                      WHERE ReportType = @ReportType AND 
                            SubReportType = @SubReportType)
     )
     OR
     (
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.Contracts 
                  WHERE ReportType = @ReportType AND 
                        SubReportType = @SubReportType)
      AND         
      A.Contract IN (SELECT DISTINCT ConC FROM DB.dbo.PData)
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create two views to normalize the column selection between the two tables (and optimize them independently with query analyzer) then in your sproc union them and filter on the new "combined" column.